# Automate Inventor SAT import with Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Is possible in Design Automation for Inventor, to automate the manual process of importing a SAT file to an assembly?

I see there is a translator add-in for SAT in Inventor `89162634-02B6-11D5-8E80-0010B541CD80`, but is not clear if it support only export, I need instead import options.

In short I need to automate the option and steps described here: https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-7CF00AFC-D40C-4FFC-B781-338AE2476527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import SAT with Design Automation is possible in general.

When you need to get Translator options (not only SAT translator), you can use following VBA code

Options with possible values are described here

https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-25D24E28-7517-4903-8AEE-123F8C71A89E&v=Inventor2023

```vb
Sub ImportSAT_Options()
    Dim satAddIn As TranslatorAddIn
    Set satAddIn = ThisApplication.ApplicationAddIns.ItemById("{89162634-02B6-11D5-8E80-0010B541CD80}")
    
    Dim oContext As TranslationContext
    Set oContext = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateTranslationContext()
    
    Dim oOptions    As NameValueMap
    Set oOptions = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap()
    
    Dim oData As DataMedium
    Set oData = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateDataMedium()
    
    If satAddIn.HasOpenOptions(oData, oContext, oOptions) Then
        Call PrintNameValueMap(oOptions)
    End If
End Sub

Sub PrintNameValueMap(namValMap As NameValueMap)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim key As String
    Dim value As Variant
    For i = 1 To namValMap.Count
        key = namValMap.name(i)
        value = namValMap.value(key)
        Debug.Print key, value
    Next
End Sub
```